# C linked list conditional statement

Tags: c

Im trying to implement a way to enter a filename into a list at the head position. Once the the list has its first entry, on my second run inside function insert, I want to enter another filename but this time in the next (pNext) position.

I have an idea on how to do it on paper but the implementation confuses me. I am able to pass a filename for the first time. But for the second try I created a condition: if (frame->pNext != NULL) { //should add to the pnext position

But instead this condition always executes before I even insert my first frame. frame->pNext is NULL but since I used malloc, it points to garbage memory so that condition will always be true, but I need it to be false only on the first run.

So that way I add a list at the head, and then the next run I add a second filename at position 2....and so on.

Example: filename: [first] [second] [third]

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE } BOOL;
struct Frame {
    char* fileName;
    struct Frame* pNext;
};

struct Animation {
    struct Frame* frames;
};

// Forward declarations
void initAnimation(struct Animation*);
void insertFrame(struct Animation*);
void runFrames(struct Animation*);

int main(void)
{
    char response;
    BOOL RUNNING = TRUE;
    struct Animation A;
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    initAnimation(&A);

    while (RUNNING)
    {
        printf("MENU\n 1. Insert a Frame\n 2. Delete all the Frames\n 3. Run the Animation\n 4. Quit\n");
        scanf("%c", &response);
        switch (response)
        {
        case '1':insertFrame(&A); break;
        case '3':runFrames(&A); break;
        case '4':RUNNING = FALSE; break;
        default:printf("Please enter a valid option\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        while ((response = getchar()) != '\n' && response != EOF);// clear input buffer
    }
    return 0;
}

void initAnimation(struct Animation* pA) {
     pA = NULL;
}

void insertFrame(struct Animation* pA) {
    char* fileName;
    struct Frame* frame; 

    fileName = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); //filename
   frame = (struct Frame *)malloc(sizeof(struct Frame)); //next frame
    frame->fileName = (struct Frame *)malloc(sizeof(struct Frame)); //filename
    frame->pNext = (struct Frame *)malloc(sizeof(struct Frame)); //for next frames

    printf("Insert a Frame in the Animation\n");
    printf("Please enter the Frame filename :");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    strcpy(frame->fileName, fileName); //store into filename

    if (frame->pNext != NULL) { //add to pnext frame
        printf("next frames");
        frame->pNext = frame;
    }
    else { //add to first frame once
        printf("this is the first frame");
        pA->frames = frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of this code is surely irrelevant.  The only thing I can say immediately is that your run of 4 `malloc`s is highly suspicious.  You probably need only 2, and surely you don't want one of them to be just 1 byte.

Comment: @DavisHerring what do you mean by just 1 byte?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1.

Comment: @DavisHerring I see, but for the structs how would I know how much memory I need to allocate?

Comment: The struct is easy, but allocate only one at a time (leaving `->pNext` null).  Strings are hard: `scanf("%s", fileName)` is intrinsically unsafe _because_ you don't know how much memory to allocate.  Modern implementations provide [%ms](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).  Otherwise you have to read and buffer and reallocate and read some more until you get it all...

Comment: It's hard to sort out fundamental architectural problems in comments.  Start by figuring out why `initAnimation` does nothing at all.

Comment: initAnimation should initialize Frame data members to 0. How should I approach this?

Comment: Why initialize a `Frame` instead of assigning to `pA->frames`?

Comment: Assigning to `pA->frames` inside `insertFrame` makes sense if you want to put the new frame at the head of the list.  Manipulating a `Frame` in `initAnimation` makes no sense because you don't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about how to make the condition only run after the first node is added. You must move the malloc into the else statement, after `pA->frames = frame`. On that note, there is some stuff that you should be aware of.

First, you are missing the `stdlib.h` library that you need for malloc. 
(source: CLion, gcc errors)

Second, the library `crtdbg.h` seems to be a C++ library rather than a C library (source: light google search).

Third, the insert frame function isn't storing the frames that are being created. This is because the variable A is not declared as a pointer. In addition to this point, when you initialize pNext in InsertFrame, you need to reference it in relation to `pA->frames`, the same goes for `frame->pNext = frame;` in the if statement.

Lastly, you might consider adding a head node that points to the first node so you can get to the beginning.

Hope this helps, good luck

Edit:
I wrote my own version of your insertFrame() function:

```
void insertFrame(struct Animation* pA) {
struct frame* frame;

frame = (struct frame *)malloc(sizeof(struct frame)); //next frame
frame->fileName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); //filename


printf("Insert a Frame in the Animation\n");
printf("Please enter the Frame filename :");
scanf("%s", frame->fileName);

//Skips to else the first time because pA->frames->pNext == Null 
//The extra if is how I stopped a segmentation fault.
if(pA->frames != NULL) {

    //Check if the current node has memory space reserved
    if (pA->frames->pNext != NULL) { //add to pnext frame
        printf("next frames\n");
        pA->frames->pNext = frame;
        pA->frames = pA->frames->pNext;
    }
}
else { //add to first frame once
    printf("this is the first frame\n");

    //fill the first frame
    pA->frames = frame;

    //Set head node next value to the first node in the list
    pA->head->pNext= pA->frames;

    //Because pA->frames->pNext is declared and initialilzed here, it keeps 
    //the if statement above from running the first time
    pA->frames->pNext = (struct frame *)malloc(sizeof(struct frame)); 
}
}
```

Edit 2:
Instead of using initAnimation, I think it makes more sense to malloc it in the main when you declare it. When you don't initialize it, or set it to NULL there's nowhere to store the frames.

Comment: Ineed the malloc before the if statement because i get a Exception thrown: read access violation
frame was 0XCCCCCCCC

Comment: How can I add at nth position and then swap if there is already a frame that exists in that current position? basically you cant only place a frame at <= nth position